# Can Ubuntu be installed in VirtualBox in Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox to set up a copy of Ubuntu for experimenting. I want it this way so that I can have a virtual/permanent copy of Ubuntu.

I am at the stage where I need to decided where to put the virtual Ubuntu. It lists the VirtualBox for boot and lists one option for the actual OS.

Is that one option the virtual box too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand. Yes, you can install Ubuntu in virtualbox. That runs as a program in your main operating system. That is not the same as dual-boot, where you have two operating system side by side but only run one at a time. That's also perfectly possible with Ubuntu, but that's something entirely different and you don't need VirtualBox for that.

I hope it answered your question. If you edit your question to be easier to understand, I can probably provide a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it wouldnt be easy to understand my description of the problem.
Basically, I want a virtual machine to have Ubuntu OS all the time...I am at the installation phase...it gives me the option to set the boot section on the virtual box, but it doesnt give me the option to install the OS on the virtual box, but show the entire hard disk. Shall I just choose the "entire hard disk"? It means the Virtual Box in this case, right?

Comment: Ah. Yes, the hardware you see in the virtual machine does not affect your real computer, so when installing Ubuntu in the virtual machine, you choose to use the entire disk. It does not mean your real harddisk, but the virtual harddisk. ;)

Comment: SOLVED: I had to choose the erase and install ubuntu option...that way it only showed the virtual box's space of 8 G.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you may use VirtualBox for Ubuntu under Ubuntu. I prefer vmware-player too.